# What are some of the largest propellers post-WWII?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller

[image]
([Source](http://www.airwar.ru/image/idop/bww1/linker2/linker2-c1.jpg))

The propeller on the [Linke-Hofmann R.II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linke-Hofmann_R.II) (1919) holds the [record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/largest-propeller-on-an-aircraft) at 6.9 m (22 ft 6 in).

What are some of the largest propellers post-WWII? Top 5 or so.

Comment: Proprotors on the [V-22 Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) are around 11.5 m (38 feet)

Comment: The Limke-Hofmann R.II had FOUR engines.

Comment: The largest propellers today are mounted on top of a large mast and connected to a generator. Here the record was held for many years by the [Growian](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growian) experimental windmill, which ran first in 1983 and had a rotor of 100m diameter. Modern [offshore windfarms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshore_wind_power) have now reached dimensions of up to 170m rotor diameter.

Comment: So, are we not counting propellers on helicopters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Google, here are some of the largest post WWII propeller diameters:

- [Antonov AN-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-22): 20'4" (6.2 m)
- [Convair B-36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker): 19' (5.8 m)
- [Douglas C-133](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-133_Cargomaster): 18' (5.5 m)
- [Hughes H-4 "Spruce Goose"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules): 17'2" (5.2 m)
- [Boeing B-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-29_Superfortress) and [B-50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-50_Superfortress): 16'7" (5.1 m)
- [Martin Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_JRM_Mars): 15'2" (4.6 m)
- [Vought Corsair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_F4U_Corsair): 13'4" (4.1 m)

Comment: Depends on what measure you use.  None of them ceased production before 1946.

Comment: It would be wonderful to see metric equivalents of these fine numbers

Comment: @Aoeuid post-WWII means "after WWII." That is, they started production 1945 or later.

Comment: [Tu-95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-95) and [Tu-114](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-114) would also be in there, as they used the same engine as the AN-22.

Comment: A400M blades are missing